# Не получается добавить шрифт neris

Tags: css, шрифты, opera

У меня есть вопрос, не могу подключить к верстаемой странице на своем ПК шрифт neris.

Точнее так - шрифт подключил, он работает в хроме, а вот в опере ну совсем не хочет (

Все делал по инструкции отсюда - https://andryushkin.ru/fonts/download-font-neris/

Прошу помощи гуру в решении вопроса.

Вот исходные данные:
1) Редактируемый файл в категории - D:\ВЕРСТКА\Тестовое задание.html
2) Список шрифтов добавленный в категорию:
[image: категория]

3) Сам код для подключения шрифта:

```html
@font-face {
    font-family: "NerisSemiBold";
    src: url("../fonts/NerisSemiBold/NerisSemiBold.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/NerisSemiBold/NerisSemiBold.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../fonts/NerisSemiBold/NerisSemiBold.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/NerisSemiBold/NerisSemiBold.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему - нужно было просто файл переименовать с кирилици на латиницу.